# Linked List Wrong Output Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hey ya'll I am having a little trouble with my singly linked list. I decided to create a simple one because we do not get enough practice during my data structures class and cannot seem to find why I am not getting the right output.

The code is:

```
package linked_list;

public class LinkedList {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;   // After figuring out head, come back to this FIXME
    private int listSize;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = new Node(null);
        tail = new Node(null);
    }

    public void addLast(String s) {
        Node newNode = new Node(s);
        if (head == null) {
            addFirst(s);
        } else {
            while (head.next != null) {
                head = head.next;
            }
            head.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        listSize++;
    }

    public void addFirst(String s) {
        Node newNode = new Node(s);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else {
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        listSize++;
    }

    public Object getFirst() {
        return head.data;
    }

    public Object getLast() {
        return tail.data;
    }

    public void clear() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        listSize = 0;
    }

    public Object peek() {
        try {
            if (head == null) {
                throw new Exception ("The value is null");
            }
            else {
                return head;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return listSize;
    }

    // This class has the ability to create the nodes that are used
    // in the Linked List.

    private class Node {
        Node next;
        Object data;

        public Node(String value) {
            next = null;
            data = value;
        }

        public Node(Object value, Node nextValue) {
            next = nextValue;
            data = value;
        }

        public Object getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Object dataValue) {
            data = dataValue;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node nextValue) {
            next = nextValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is my driver that I created to run a simple little operation:

```
package linked_list;

public class LinkedListDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();

        list1.clear();

        list1.addLast("This goes last");
        list1.addFirst("This goes first");
        list1.addLast("Now this one goes last");

        System.out.println(list1.getFirst());
        System.out.println(list1.getLast());
    }

}
```

My output is this:

```
This goes last
Now this one goes last
```

I guess my question is why am I not getting the answer `This goes first` from my `getFirst()` method. It seems to be something wrong with the order or structure of that method but I cannot pinpoint it.

Comment: Debug your code before to write a question

Answer (score 3):

When you are in the else in the addLast, you are changing the reference to head. You should use another reference pointer to traverse the list when adding in the else.

Also, your list size should only be incremented in the else in addLast because you are incrementing twice otherwise (once in addFirst and again after the if-else in addLast).